# How to setup AWS to exchange traffic between two elastic beanstalk instances on the same VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, private, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, vpc

I need to pass trafffic across two ebs instances on the same AWS VPC.

Let's say I have a VPC with a subnet 10.0.0.0/24 and two running ebs instances 
A and B with addresses 10.0.0.130 and 10.0.0.160 respectively. I need to send traffic from A to B.

Currently everything seems to be working fine, as I configure A to send traffic to 10.0.0.130, but I am not confident that this IP address will survive a redeploy.

How can I make sure the **private** 10.0.0.130 IP addresses is static, or to use some sort of **private/internal DNS** to make sure I always send traffic to the proper IP address for instance B?

Comment: Those IP's are not static, you can put an elastic load balancer in front your ec2 instances and associate route 53 DNS to LB. It is easy if you have a scripted deployment using cloudformation.

Comment: @titogeo maybe you should explain how an elastic load balancer will solve the issue of inter-server communication? I don't see how that will help.

Comment: @titogeo, is an elastic load balancer useful for inter VPC communication? I though I would need it only if traffic was coming from the public internet.

Comment: you can have an internal load balancer and a private hosted zone in route 53.

Comment: @titogeo how would a load balancer know the request is coming from one server, and always be sure it routes that request to the other server? If both servers are in the load balancer's pool the requests would be randomly routed back to the same server making the request 50% of the time.

Comment: nope, I mean one lb -> one instance. let's say a.example.com and b.example.com. these will be static even if the instance is replaced.

Comment: @RuiFerrão https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/internal-elastic-load-balancers/

Comment: @titogeo you are absolutely right, it works perfectly!

Comment: @titogeo how will you get Elastic Beanstalk to register new instances with the load balancers, every time a redeploy, or an instance replacement happens?

Comment: That's why I mentioned Cloudformation, you will need ELB, an Autoscaling group and target group. If you have this setup new instances will get automatically registered - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/autoscaling-load-balancer.html --- https://gist.github.com/istvano/6262108

Comment: @titogeo So you suggest that they stop using Elastic Beanstalk entirely, instead creating multiple load balancers,each with an auto-scaling group of max-size == `1`? Because that's the only way each internal load balancer is going to stay up-to-date with redeployments.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in thinking that those IP addresses will not survive a redeploy. Those IP addresses won't even survive a scale-in, scale-out, or server failing health check event.

I would try tagging the EC2 instances as part of the EB deployment, and then add some code to the instances that queries the AWS API for the list of instances with those tags. Given that each instance should know its own IP address, it should then be easy to determine what the IP address of the other server is.

Comment: The solution you describe requires committing my application with the aws api.. I just want to perform a simple http client request to the other server on the same VPC and leave the matters of making sure the request always hits the right IP in the infrastructure setup and not on the application code.

Comment: @RuiFerrão I missed the part in your question where you stated the solution can't include calls to the AWS API. Amazon has a description of several types of service discovery methods [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-technical-content/latest/microservices-on-aws/service-discovery.html#service-discovery-using-key-value-store) but those involve making calls to the AWS API at some point, and since EB is going to be replacing your servers whenever it feels like it, I don't see how you would avoid making AWS API calls unless you implement some sort of third-party service registry.

Comment: Just edited the question title to better reflect what I was looking for, @titogeo suggestion worked for me.

Comment: @RuiFerrão that load balancer thing is going to add lots of extra costs, and I'm not convinced it will work automatically through redeployments. Have you tried a redeploy after setting that up?

Comment: I have performed an `eb deploy` a couple of times, but the IP address did not changed, so I could not test it properly...

Comment: Since `eb deploy` was not causing an IP address change, I have now performed a *Rebuild Environment* and indeed nothing worked after that... Not only I had to rebuild the Load Balancer configuration, but also the Service Groups associated with the instance were replaced by a new set of default ones... So if all that I do is a new deploy, it seems no load balancer is needed and I can just hardcode the IP address on the configuration. But if the environment is rebuild, I have to manually reconfigure everything...

Comment: @RuiFerrão you also need to be prepared for your EC2 instance to experience hardware degradation, at which point EB will replace it with a different instance, which will have a different IP address. You can't rely on the IPs to stay static.

Comment: I am really disappointed at this.. It seems like only the standard publicly exposed setup is accounted for in beanstalk.. Is it so strange to want to keep my APIs private? I am really questioning giving up on this and moving back to EC2 and manually manage everything myself, since it seems that is the path I am being pushed for already...

Comment: If you are doing anything other than a simple load-balanced website, you probably don't want to use Elastic Beanstalk. EB manages a basic AWS setup for people that don't know how to otherwise use AWS. I don't recommend it for anything like what you are doing.

Comment: I understand.. But the whole _don't worry with managing/updating the OS/plaform_ is just so compelling.. It feels ackward to go back to managing all of that... Anyway, thanks for the all the help!